# LabVIEW GUI for Keithley 2400 source meter

Tags: matlab, labview

So I am trying to use a computer and Keithley 2400 source meter to run current vs. voltage graphs (IV curves). I’ve tried using LabVIEW but found only old drivers that didn’t seem to work. I have found success with Matlab but now I am trying to not only run IV curves, but also be able to run current through the devices using only a computer and basically use the source meter and control its settings only through a computer. I think LabVIEW will provide the easiest interface in order to control everything, but I was wondering if anyone else has done this, or where I can find updated drivers and software to achieve this.

Comment: The commands for controlling the instrument are in the user manual, so you can use whatever programming language you want to send those commands without any special drivers. See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43486-kpib-kenny-purpose-interface-bus) for some Matlab code I wrote for this kind of project. Otherwise, you can download drivers from the Tek website that you can use with Matlab or LabView or whatever. Tek also sells a python-based programming solution called ACS.

Comment: Thank you! Would you happen to know if there is a list of matlab commands that I could use to communicate with the keithley 2400?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that drivers should work for you, maybe you did some wrong setup. Here you can find LabVIEW drivers - http://sine.ni.com/apps/utf8/niid_web_display.download_page?p_id_guid=25B255F3AA83660EE0440003BA7CCD71. Even if they are made using NI-VISA 5.4, they still could be used in the latest LabVIEW versions.

Before using LabVIEW, make sure that you can communicate with device either via NI VISA Test Panel, or some other serial console (like RealTerm). When communication is established, apply same settings to LabVIEW code. Also make sure, that proper termination character is used on LabVIEW side.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have tried to download the drivers but when I try to open a program it has an error finding the paths to each file, do I need to run a specific initializing program first?